# Merge multiple parquet files into single file on S3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I don't want to partition or repartition the spark dataframe and write multiple part files as it gives the best performance. Is there any way I can merge the files after it has been written to S3.

I have used parquet-tools and it does the merge to local files. I want to do this on S3.

Comment: No. Files in s3 are immutable. Read parts, append, write again.

Comment: Is there anyway i can merge and write to a different location. ?

Comment: What do you mean? Once you read the data say in spark with `spark.read.parquet("s3a://..` write wherever you want. Make a new folder in same bucket, overwrite, whatever..

Comment: I don't want to read it again in spark, as it will again have multiple partitions. I want a single parquet file out and repartitioning is expensive so I want to avoid that.

Comment: You can append 2 files on S3 without downloading if it works for you

Comment: Appending is not a problem, Parquet files are the columnar format. They become corrupted if you just merge/append one into another.

Comment: I had the similar issue and as of now repartitioning seems the only fair solution. How did you solve it?